# How to encrypt adonis js 5 response data using middleware

Tags: response, middleware, adonis.js

I want to encrypt data sent from adonis js 5 response using middleware.

I am returning response data from my service class api to react front end in this way:

```
public async login(username:string,password:string)
{
   return {'status':'success','data':{'username':username,'password':password }};
}
```

Now I want to get hold of this data in adonis js 5 middleware and first encrypt it and then send to client. I am unable to get hold of returned response data in adonis js 5 middleware. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new middleware class using adonis cli let's say `EncryptMiddleware`. [Source](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/middleware#middleware-classes)

```
node ace make:middleware EncryptMiddleware
```

- Register your middleware file as global or named middleware in `kernel.ts` file. [Source](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/middleware#registering-middleware)

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Server.middleware.register([() => import('App/Middleware/EncryptMiddleware')])
```

Or

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Named middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Server.middleware.registerNamed({ encryptResponse: () => import('App/Middleware/EncryptMiddleware') })
```

- If you use named middleware then you have to use it on each Route or Route group needed. Like the following:

```
Route.get('dashboard', 'DashboardController.index').middleware('encryptResponse') //
```

- Now add your encryption logic to your `EncryptMiddleware` class in `App/Middleware/EncryptMiddleware`. [Source](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/middleware#about-middleware-class)

```
import Encryption from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Encryption'
import { HttpContextContract } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext'

export default class EncryptMiddleware {
  public async handle(
    { response, request }: HttpContextContract,
    next: () => Promise<void>
  ) {
    // Some encryption logic => e.g. encrypt body here
    const encryptedResponse = Encryption.encrypt(request.body())

    // Send encrypted data to the response
    response.send(encryptedResponse)

    await next()
  }
}
```

- Result: you will get encrypted response body, now you have to decrypt response on the client.

Comment: Do you have client side encrpt descrypt code ? @felmez

Comment: @DarshitHedpara, nope sorry, but you can create a decryption logic based on the same encryption algorithm used in the encryption. [Adonis Encryption](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/security/encryption)

Comment: I tried many things online but couldn't decrpyt with appKey of adonisjs with same algorithm used by adonijs @felmez